# How to check if two objects collided Objective C

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, collision

I am trying to detect if two objects collide. I have set up my player and enemy the same way as it appears in the code. I am using Tiled and trying to get the objects detect the player, but I cant detect collision. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks. Sample code as follows:

```
-(void)addEnemyAtX:(int)x y:(int)y {
self.enemy = [[Enemy alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"door_closed.png"];
self.enemy.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
self.enemy.zPosition = 15;
self.enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:self.enemy.texture size:self.enemy.texture.size];
self.enemy.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
self.enemy.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
[self.map addChild:self.enemy];
  SKAction *action3 = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.enemy.position.x + 200,self.enemy.position.y) duration:3.0];
  SKAction *action2 = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.enemy.position.x,self.enemy.position.y) duration:3.0];
  SKAction *group = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[action3, action2]]];

  [self.enemy runAction:group];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll first need to set the player’s and the enemy’s physic bodies `categoryBitMask` property.

If you really mean ‘collide’ i.e. for the objects to bounce off each other, then this should happen automatically as this is controlled by the physics body’s `collisionBitMask` but initially this is `UInt32.Max`, so everything collides with everything.

If you actually mean ‘contact’, so that your `didBegin` code gets called when the objects touch, you’ll need to set up the `contactTestBitMask` as this is initially 0 i.e. nothing contacts anything.

Edit:

As Maria said - set the delegate and also make sure your class is an `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`. Your code won’t be notified of any contacts if you don’t. (These steps are only required if you want contact detection - collisions dont need them.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
   physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

I suspect that you want something to happen when the player and the enemy touch, so I *think* you really want contact detection, not collisions.

Comment: Don’t forget to add delegate to the class’ interface (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicscontactdelegate?language=objc)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. I added physics bodies to the  player and the enemy.

  self.enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = obs1Category;
  self.enemy.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ballCategory;
  self.enemy.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory;
  self.enemy.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;

Then called 

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{
  
  NSLog(@"contact detected");
  [self.contactQueue addObject:contact];
  [self gameOver:0];
}